# When merging with related objects included, new relationships are not persisted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have run into some strange behaviour with my SQLAlchemy models when I try to update data. I have a one to many relationship defined like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"
] = "postgresql://geonatadmin:monpassachanger@localhost:5432/geonature2db_test"
app.debug = True
DB = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Child(DB.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Child"

    id_child = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_parent = DB.Column(DB.Integer, ForeignKey("Parent.id_parent"))
    name = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(50))


class Parent(DB.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Parent"

    id_parent = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(50))

    childrens = relationship("Child", lazy="joined", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

DB.create_all()
```

I'm trying to update `Parent` and `Child` from JSON sent from my API. In my example a parent has already one child, and I try to add two new children to it:

```
with app.app_context():
    first_json = {"name": "parent1", "childrens": [{"name": "john"}]}
    childrens = first_json.pop("childrens")
    parent = Parent(**first_json)
    for child in childrens:
        parent.childrens.append(Child(**child))

    DB.session.add(parent)
    DB.session.commit()
    DB.session.flush()

    second_json = {
        "id_parent": 1,
        "name": "parent1",
        "childrens": [
            {"id_child": 1, "name": "john"},
            {"id_child": None, "name": "foo"},
            {"id_child": None, "name": "bar"},
        ],
    }
    childrens = second_json.pop("childrens")
    parent = Parent(**second_json)
    for child in childrens:
        parent.childrens.append(Child(**child))

    DB.session.merge(parent)
    DB.session.commit()
```

Finally I only have Child 1 and Child 3 in my database. Child 2 is never added.

I tried to get more information about the actual SQL emitted with this configuration:

```
current_app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True
```

and indeed, there is no INSERT statement for Child 2.

Comment: I edit my post with a more complete code example. The code I provide actually work and I do not succeed to reproduce the exact comportement of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnally figure out that if I remove the 'id_child" when it is None, the merge work fine.
 Like this:

```
second_json = {
    "id_parent": 1,
    "name": "parent1",
    "childrens": [
        {"id_child": 1, "name": "john"},
        {"name": "foo"},
        {"name": "bar"},
    ],
}
```